# File_get_contents not working?

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook, file-get-contents

I am using cakephp. I am trying get data from facebook using file_get_contents. I get a warning.

> Warning (2): file_get_contents()
>   [function.file-get-contents]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server
>   configuration  Warning (2):
>   file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/?access_token=111978178XXXXXX|2.lg65A3c0atficNsFcf7Rog__.3600.12799XXXX-1000

Is there any way to get the data?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a configuration issue on your server.

In your php.ini you most probably have

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

If you want to allow this, set it to on. Be aware though that the reason it's turned off by default is that it's more secure.

A common alternative is to use cURL instead; you might want to check if your hosting environment offers that.

Comment: And for this reason it is likely that your hosting provider will block you from setting it in a local php.ini (unless you have unshared hosting).