# How to obtain location from ipinfo.io in PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

I am using [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io) to get my current city (location) using PHP.

However, I am not able to see my city when using this piece of code.

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/geo");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details->city;
```

I don't know where the error is.

Comment: And what is the error? What Have you tried? What are the logs? What does var_dump(j$json) output? PS. Thx for a great portal addrres for the future :).

Comment: I tried to echo  $json = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/geo');  but there is nothing that appears - still with blank screen.

Comment: Try: var_dump(file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/geo')); If this does not show anything something is not ok with server configuration... Probably it blocks (how, and why?) getting contents from external IPs. Notice HTTP:// in my code.

Comment: Tried to var dump - still blank. Do you think IPINFO is blocking me somehow?

Comment: Have You tried with http://? I updated my comment few seconds before.

Comment: Off topic, but anyway: for my IP, the given estimated "City" is 350 km / 200 miles off from my real one. I don't know on what database they are working, but it's not __that__ precise ...

Comment: You need to specify the protocol (`http://`) when using file_get_contents to open an URL. And sometimes opening URLs through file_get_contents may be disabled, in which case you'll need to use curl or an HTTP client library.

Comment: @maytham my ISP is another 500 miles away :/ I live south of Munich, ipinfo claims me in Aalen, my ISP is in Düsseldorf and I have a static IP since 8 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getClientIP(){
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  return $ip;
}

$ipaddress = getClientIP();

function ip_details($ip) {
  $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/geo");
  $details = json_decode($json, true);
  return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details['city'];
```

this should work.

however, I recommend you to get used to use curl instead of file_get_contents(), if you want a online resource. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522668/3160141

Comment: the $ipaddress part is correct. I can get the ip address of client. However, the IPINFO part returns null - blank screen.

Comment: there was a mistake, I tipped json_dencode() instead a json_decode()

Comment: Still blank. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Found the issue - the Rackspace box I'm running this is shared and there are other scripts on that box which use ipinfo. The ip address of that box is blocked due to the limit being exceeded.

Comment: Worked like a charm, except I had to add the token - `http://ipinfo.io?token={your_account_token}/{$ip}/geo` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you working on localhost? Try the following code:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/geo");
    $details = json_decode($json); // HERE!!!
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details->ip; // CHANGE TO IP!!!
```

If it returns Your IP, everything is OK, Your IP is probably `127.0.0.1`, and this site does not know the location, so `$details->city` is not set. You must check `if (isset($details->city))` and make an alternative script if the city is not there.

---

I see You still got problems. Try to do something like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/geo');
var_dump($string);
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
var_dump($ipaddress); 
$string2 = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'.$ipaddress.'/geo');
var_dump($string2);
```

And write in comments which one failed ;).

---

**If only IP part is OK, try to read this one:** [File_get_contents not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324524/file-get-contents-not-working)

And also run this code with maximum error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Before this part of code.

Comment: Running on an external server, not localhost. No IP returned which is weird. Is it IPINFO that is not allowing me from running on that external server?

Comment: This is impossible. I will update my answer in a few minutes. Updated! Try to debug it in that simple way... Maybe it will help to find the problem.

Comment: First one failed. Last one - bool(false)  I can dump my IP address ($ipaddress) fine though.

Comment: Updated (bottom few lines...). You can try to file_get_contents on local file and see if it works as a function.

Comment: This works - provided that you have a paid plan and that your IP hasn't been blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but for people currently looking for this same question, this will solve the problem if it's on Localhost:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];

  function ip_details($ip) {
     $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/");
     $details = json_decode($json); // decode json with geolocalization information
     return $details;
  }

 $details = ip_details($ipaddress);
 echo $details->ip; // Use city, ip or other thing... see https://ipinfo.io
```

If it is on Web Server Only use this:

```
$server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //in localhost this is ::1
echo "Your IP is: ".$server;
```

Note: The 2 codes will get the public ip, the 1st code gets the public ip by Localhost and the 2nd code gets the public ip by the web server. :)